# Zeppelin Clojure throwing ClassNotFoundException/NoClassDefFoundError for external dependency

Tags: java, maven, clojure, interpreter, apache-zeppelin

I have added Clojure interpreter to the Zeppelin project. I'm able to run Clojure code into the notebook.

I have added few dependency into interpreter setting (ex. hbase-client). I'm able to call classes from the dependency into the notebook.

[image]

Everything is fine till here but the problem is I have added one of my projects. I want to call some function from that project into the notebook.

```
%clj
(use 'some.dep.core)
(create-db "formcept:hbase://test")
```

[image]

Here the dependency which I'm using is dependent on hbase. And it's throwing `ClassNotFoundException` on first run and `NoClassDefFoundError Could not initialize class some.dep.core__init  java.lang.Class.forName0 (Class.java:-2)`
[image]

I have tried following:
I have added dependencies into zeppelin classpath from `interpreter.sh` and `zeppelin-daemon.sh`.
I have added dependencies into interpreter setting.
I have tried with uber-jar(JAR with dependencies).

Can anyone share the best way to inject external dependency and call it from notepad?

Thanks :)

Comment: did you ever get it working ? Is there a clojure interpreter available now ?